# How to show TexView and ImageView from SD Card within ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, textview, imageview

I would really appreciate help with my query. 
The app I am building is downloading text and images from a web address (using JSON) and storing the text in a sqlite database, and the images in the SD Card of the phone.
I then want to show the text and the associated image in a listView.
I have no issues showing the text, but I am not able to show the imageView.

Below is the code within MainActivity that picks up the text from the sqlite database and populates a list string.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void displayListView() {
   IgroDatabaseHelper helper = new IgroDatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
   globalVariable.userLang = helper.userLanguage();
   ArticlesTable = globalVariable.userLang + "Articles";
   numRows = helper.NumEntries(ArticlesTable);
   int i = 1;
   String headText;
   String artID;
   String Date;
   File imgFile;
   List<String> headingArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // array holding the headings to show in TextView
   List<String> artIDArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // array of article IDs used to get the name of the corresponding image
   List<String> imgArray = new ArrayList<String>();    
   File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   String filename;
while (i <= numRows){ //loop over the number of Articles headings
       headText = helper.getTextFromTable(ArticlesTable, i, "heading");
       artID = helper.getTextFromTable(ArticlesTable, i, "artID");
       image = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + artID + ".png”;
       // getting the image to be shown
       filename= artID + ".png"; 
       imgFile = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
       Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());            
       headingArray.add(headText);
       artIDArray.add(artID);
       imgArray.add(filename);
       i= i + 1;
}           

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    R.layout.article_row, R.id.heading, headingArray);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
 }
}
```

Below is the article_row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background = "#5a9b3e"
android:alpha = "0.7"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:alpha = "1.0"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/smallimage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>      
 </LinearLayout>
```

I don't think I am using the correct data structure, as even though it shows the text, I am not able to combine the image. But I don't know what data structure to use in order to be able hold the text and image and populate it within a while loop.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanking all of you in advance!

Comment: Read [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/loading-listview-with-sdcard-thumbnail-images-and-displaying-its-title-size-width-and-height-by-merging-cursors-using-matrixcursor/), it's a good tutorial

Comment: @tianyu thank you. Another member has suggested the same tutorial. I had done extensive research and had not found it before, so thank you for pointing it out to me. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @tianyu I have a question. At the moment I loop over the number of rows in the table to display the text, do I still do this and within the while loop call the Loader<Cursor> function? It is not clear to me how to use it in that way. Would you know? Thanks

Comment: In your code, you can call `smallimage.setImageBitmap()` after `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` to set the image.  And it's better do `decodeFile()` in `AsyncTask.doInBackground(...)`. If you are using the tutorial you may need to get 'heading' information of each image according to file's name.

Comment: Thank you, how do I then add it to the matrixCursor?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly display images from server without saving them. But if you want to do the same you should try this method to list images from SDCard

[Loading ListView Image From SDCard](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/loading-listview-with-sdcard-thumbnail-images-and-displaying-its-title-size-width-and-height-by-merging-cursors-using-matrixcursor/)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will work my way through the tutorial and attempt to adapt it to my needs. For example, how to add the headings from the sqlite database. I will get back to you with, I hope, a success story! Thanks again.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me if I can put the code in the link within the while loop? How to I loop over the rows in the table to get the text? Thanks very much.

Comment: Send me the code that you are using so that i can help you

Comment: Thank you that is very kind of you. Do you want me to send you My MainActivity.java and the 2 XML files I have? How exactly can I send it to you? Thanks!

Comment: Would you send me your email address or some other way to send you the code? Again, thanks a lot!